# jsreportonline - How to save in pdf file

Tags: node.js, request, jsreport

I've finally got the jsreportonline at least generating the file. Here's my code:

```
request.post({
  url: 'https://xxxx.jsreportonline.net/api/report',
  json: true,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization" : "Basic "+new Buffer(username:pwd).toString('base64')
  },
  body: {
    "template" : {'shortid" : xxxxx},
    "data" : xxxx,
  }
}, function(err, res, body) {
  **** HERE IS THE PROBLEM ****
});
```

I have no clue how to write the pdf output stored within variable 'body' to a file. I've tried:

```
var pbs = fs.createWriteStream('./report.pdf');
pbs.write(body);
pbs.end();
```

I've tried:

```
var pbs = fs.createWriteStream('./report.pdf', {defaultEncoding: 'binary'});
```

... but the PDF file never is displayed properly. I know the code works because I can set an option on the call:

```
"options" : {
  "reports" : {"save" : true}
}
```

... and the report is saved to my jsreportonline account and renders fine.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the callback but rather directly pipe the stream returned from the `request.post`. See this in docs [here](https://github.com/request/request#streaming). Example:

```
var request = require('request')
var fs = require('fs')

request.post({
  url: 'https://xxx.jsreportonline.net/api/report',
  json: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : 'Basic '+new Buffer('xxx:yyy').toString('base64')
  },
  body: {
    'template' : {'shortid" : xxxxx},
    'data' : xxxx,
 }
}).on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err)
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('report.pdf'))
```

Comment: It creates the report now. Thank you. However, when it returns from jsreport, and creates the pdf report it does not render properly in either Firefox or Chrome. However, if I open-up the saved pdf file in Firefox/Chrome, it renders fine. Only when it returns does it fail to render.

Comment: Hm, maybe try to return static pdf file and troubleshoot if it works it without jsreport

Comment: I believe now it's a race-condition between (I assume) the async .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(...)) and when I call fs.readFile.

Comment: Fixed. Needed to put a callback on the pipe call. As in, .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(...).on('finish', function() {...});

Comment: How can i give my specific path to save pdf in place of C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Temp ????? –

Answer (score 1):

You can use **'busboy'** to write the uploaded file to a file in server directory.

**Saving the file:-**

```
var

express = require("express"), os = require('os'), path = require('path'), Busboy = require('busboy'), fs = require('fs'), app = express();

app.post('/savepdf', function(req, res) {

    var busboy = new Busboy({
        headers : req.headers
    });

    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log("OS tmp dir ========>" + os.tmpDir());
        console.log("Base name ========>" + path.basename(filename));
        var saveTo = path.join(os.tmpDir(), path.basename(filename));
        file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Connection' : 'close'
        });
        console.log("Upload finished !!!");
        res.end("Success!");
    });
    return req.pipe(busboy);

});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('app started ');
```

**HTML Page used to test the file:-**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Post Tool</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Save PDF </h1>
        <h2>Upload Document</h2>
        <form action="/savepdf" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="uploadtext" id="uploadtext" value="Good" />
    Choose a file : <input type="file" name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile" multiple/>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:-**

The file has been saved successfully in temp folder (i.e. windows path below).

C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Temp

The **file name** would be same as the uploaded file name.

Comment: How can i give my specific path to save pdf in place of C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Temp   ?????

Comment: It is not recommended. Probably, for local testing purpose, you can try that.

Comment: for server what i need to do?

Comment: And how can i give pdf name manually while creating pdf ?

Need Help

Thanks in advance